# Laravel how to slove Undefined variable in included modal

Tags: php, laravel

How to slove `Undefined variable` error exception for variable declared in another controller.

I have **OrderController** and **CustomerController**.
In **CustomerController** i pass `$customerTypes[]` to view.
Then that view i try to import in antoher view of **OrderController** and than i get undefended variable. So OrderController does not know about `$customerTypes[]`.

How is possible to slove that dependency?
If i declare `$customerTypes[]` in OrderController that not be clean code!No point for that var in order.

**CustomerController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CustomerController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Index
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20)->withQueryString();
        $customerTypes = CustomerType::orderBy('name')->get();

        return view('customer.index', [
            'customerTypes'=> $customerTypes
        ]);
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/customer/create_modal.blade.php**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade">
    @if($customerTypes)
       @foreach($customerTypes as $type)
            <div class="form-check">
               <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $type->id }}">
                <label>{{ $type->name }}</label>
            </div>
      @endforeach
   @endif              
</div>
```

**OrderController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class OrderController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Index
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //....
        return view('customer.index', [
            'orders'=> $orders
        ]);
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/order/index.blade.php**

here i include modal and get error.

```
@include('customer.create_modal')
```

Comment: You need to pass the variable `@include('customer.create_modal', ['customerTypes' => $customerTypes])`

Comment: In addition to actually passing the variable to your `create_modal`, did you try `@isset($customerTypes)` instead of `@if($customerTypes)`? `@isset()` will handle the case when the `$customerTypes` variable hasn't been set, `@if()` only handles if it is "truthy". Also, you generally don't need `@if()` before `@foreach()`; as long as the variable is not `null`, `@foreach()` will simply do nothing if the array/collection is empty.